How to make a ball always bounce like in the game One More Bounce using Box2D?
I'm coding a game with Flutter and the flame_forge2d package (which uses Box2D internally). I want to make a game whose principle is similar to that of the game One More Bounce (a game where you have to move a ball forward by placing bars on which the ball bounces).
In One More Bounce, the player controls a ball that ALWAYS bounces (no matter the forces applied). The advantage of such behavior is that the ball never gets stuck in a corner (which would be bad since the aim of the game is precisely to make the ball bounce by placing paddles at the bottom). I would like to have the same behavior but everything I have tested so far does not allow the ball to bounce in all situations. I don't know if the One More Bounce developers used Box2D or a custom collision system. Anyway, I would like to have the same behavior!
When the ball hits another object, this is what I do (that does not prevent the ball from stopping) :
  @override
  void endContact(Object other, Contact contact) {
    super.endContact(other, contact);

    final linearVelocity = body.linearVelocity.clone();
    final length = linearVelocity.normalize();

    if (length < 1) {
      body.linearVelocity = linearVelocity * 1;
    }
  }

If you have any ideas on how to do this (or if we literally need to change the basic behavior of the ball), I'm all ears.

This line
body.linearVelocity = linearVelocity * 1;

does nothing as you are multiplying with one and length is never less than one as it is the length of the normalised vector which is one.
To get a bounce that never stops, instead of overriding the postContact try setting the friction of both the ball and the platform to zero.

linearVelocity.normalize() normalize the vector and returns its length before normalization. So it can be less than 1.
After that,
body.linearVelocity = linearVelocity * 1; changes the speed of the ball to a minimal.
Also, the friction are already set to 0. But the ball stops under some conditions (usually in corners or when hitting some target around a corner)
